# Line detection, pepper salt image

Tags: opencv, lines, hough-transform, canny-operator

[image]

Is there a way to detect the straight lines in the given image automatically?

If so, can you point me to a paper, or article, etc. in order for me to understand how this is done. Ultimately could you provide some code (e.g., OpenCV) that does that?

Thanks so much!

Comment: I'd recommend giving the Hugh Line Transform a try for the image. Should be what you're looking for. [link](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html) [another example](http://opencvexamples.blogspot.com/2013/10/line-detection-by-hough-line-transform.html)

Comment: why the down vote?

Comment: The houghLineTransform did not work... may be do to the parameters I used. I'll keep trying.

Comment: What you could try is to use a min-filter to partly remove the salt / increase the amount of black points in combination with [morphological operations](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're still interested, but check out this article [on using dilation and erosion.](https://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d1/dee/tutorial_moprh_lines_detection.html)

I haven't spent too much time on this, but I'm able to pull out this image from the original salt and pepper image. I'll upload code to Github and edit this post with a link later this day.[image]

Not sure if it is exactly what you're looking for, but it is a start in the right direction I think.